# My mobile responsive website always displays the smallest CSS width view - What might be causing this?

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I am working on a mobile responsive website which is designed for iPhone 6 Plus and smaller. (iPhone 6 & 5 for now).

When displaying in using "Inspect element" via Chrome browser and setting a device of ones I mentioned above - it works fine.

When displaying it on the real mobiles I only get the smallest width.

```
@media (max-width: 415px) {
...
}

@media (min-width :  320px) and (max-width : 375px ) {
...
}

@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) {
...
}
```

I used both of these in my HTML :

```
<!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"-->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=0" />
```

I cant paste all my code here, I have no permission.

**What other problems might cause this? 
Are there better ways to test mobile responsive websites? Because it seems like testing it on chrome or websites like 'screenfly' aren't that reliableץ**

Comment: where would a 500px fit? Also, chrome dev tools helps as it as a 'media' option (top left of inspector)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be having same `min-width` and `max-width` at `320px`

So, try this:

```
@media (min-width :  321px) and (max-width : 375px ) {
...
}

@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) {
...
}
```

Comment: +1 As the iPhone typically has a CSS pixel width of 320px and the smallest media query is defined last, this is likely to be the issue.